# 500 Error on /admin/system sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

im using the docker hub version sonarqube:6.7

this was an upgrade from sonarqube:6.5

when i go to /admin/system url i get the following from the administration tab and click on system

The request cannot be processed. Try again later.

in the logs

```
2017.11.29 18:59:45 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/system/info failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:348)
at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletResponse$ServletStream.reset(ServletResponse.java:79)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.sendErrors(WebServiceEngine.java:135)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:105)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:86)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What's your question? Can you rephrase your message so it's more clear? You should add some more tags as well

Comment: Did you run the upgrade first and did you check the SonarQube log after the upgrade?

Comment: it seems like a bug, that when a request to the endpoint /admin/system causes a 500 error with the error log, this occurred after sonarqube was finished the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, it will be fixed in [SonarQube 6.7.1](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10060)